# Updates and Deletions not working with DB2 in XPages

Tags: jdbc, db2, xpages

I've been struggling a bit to update and delete records in DB2 from XPages using JDBC in the 853 Extension Library.

Firstly, I can confirm that @JDBCInsert works perfectly. I can also view data from DB2 in many different ways. However, when trying to perform an update or delete, it just doesn't work.

My first attempt was using the JDBCRowSet Data Source. The idea here was to work with the Cached Result Set, and then in the end, commit the Changes to DB2. I was able to manipulate the Cached Result Set by modifying values and performing deletes, but when I run the dataset.acceptChanges() function, I receive the following message:

**Error calling method 'acceptChanges()' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc.model.JdbcRowSetAccessor'**

Another message from the Log is:

**DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=53, DRIVER=3.57.82**

I am logging into DB2 as Administrator, so it can't be an access issue, especially because I can insert records. I tried using the Connection Manager Control and setting the AutoCommit = true, but that doesn't change the error that gets returned.

So, my next attempt was to perform updates using @JDBCUpdate instead of working with a cached Result Set. This function doesn't work, but returns no error as well. It's almost as if it does nothing.

Finally, I attempted the @JDBCExecuteQuery to perform the update, but I get a message returned saying that I'm not allowed to perform updates using this function.

Here's some examples of what I tried that failed:

**//Here are the Values I want to change that I parse as JSON.**

```
    var v = {
        VENUE_NAME: getComponent("inputVenue").getValue(),
        ADDRESS: getComponent("inputTextareaAddress").getValue(),
        TEL_NUMBER: getComponent("inputTelNumber").getValue(),      
        CELL_NUMBER: getComponent("inputCellNumber").getValue(),
        EMAIL: getComponent("inputEmail").getValue(),
        RATE: getComponent("inputRate").getValue(),
        INCLUDES: getComponent("checkIncludes").getValue()
    }
```

@JdbcUpdate("db2","TABLE",v, "ID = 123");

@JdbcUpdate("db2","TABLE",v, "ID = '123'");

**//This Insert Function using the same JSON Array works.**

@JdbcInsert("db2","TABLE",v);

**//I use this when trying to commit the changes using a RowSet, which returns the above error messages**

JDBCRowSet.acceptChanges();

I've spent quite a lot of time with this, and right now my mind boggles.

Please help.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet to give this part of the ext lib a try, however I did notice your syntax is different than I remember, it appears like this:

```
@JdbcUpdate("dt2","users",v,"id=?",id)
```

on this documentation.

http://library.constantcontact.com/download/get/file/1102786224071-334/2011NOV18+XPages+Goes+Relational.pdf

Comment: Hi. I will check this out on Monday. Many thanks for the feedback.